# How to schedule the first replica of a statefulset to a specific node

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-statefulset

I have a StatefulSet with several replicas, for example 3 and multiple kubernetes Node in two zones.

I want to place the **FIRST** replica in the selected zone and the rest in the others zones.

- mysts-0-0 < **main_zone**
- mysts-0-1 < back_zone
- mysts-0-2 < back_zone

Why the first one? Each pod is a database instance. Replication is configured between them. And by default the first node is master.

So I want to be able to influence where the first node is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported in `StatefulSet`, as the Pod-template is identical for each replica.

You might be able to achieve this by writing a custom scheduler. For inspiration, see this article for a custom scheduler for CockroachDB: [A Custom Kubernetes Scheduler to Orchestrate Highly Available Applications](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/12/21/writing-crl-scheduler/)